# Перезагрузить вкладку из другой вкладки

Tags: php, вкладки, javascript

Такая ситуация: нужно сделать радио на сайт. Фишка в том, что мы открываем его в отдельной вкладке, а в другой лазим по сайту. Ну сделать, чтоб когда на второй вкладке мы переключаем радио, первая вкладка должна перезагрузиться с новым радио. В каком направлении гуглить?

Comment: Добавь тэг `javascript`.

Comment: localstorage events/cookie (setTimeout )


http://html5demos.com/storage-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В направлении var w = window.open(); $(w.document.body).html( msg );
Конкретно этот код обновляет содержимое другой вкладки, а не перезагружает, но что мешает загрузить нужный контент в первой вкладке и оправить его во второю?